# heroku change java version - deploy:war

Tags: java, heroku, version

im develop with the deploy:war plugin, now i get one error, that seems to be reasoned by java version.

i red this help about the system.propertys file and git add, but i dont want to use git, just deploy the final war. 
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/add-java-version-to-an-existing-maven-app

so how can i change the java version :D?

Would be appreciated if somone could help me out here,

regards

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [Heroku Maven Plugin](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-java-applications-with-the-heroku-maven-plugin), which will allow you to configure the Java version in your `pom.xml` without the need for Git. You configuration might look something like this:

`<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>com.heroku.sdk</groupId>
      <artifactId>heroku-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>0.3.4</version>
      <configuration>
        <appName>${heroku.appName}</appName>
        <jdkVersion>1.7</jdkVersion>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>`

Then you would deploy with this command:

```
$ mvn heroku:deploy-war
```

I'm not sure what Java version you're using locally, but be aware that this plugin probably won't work with Java 6.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just deploy the final WAR.  It has (presumably) been built with Java 8 as the target platform.  If so, it won't run on Java 8 or earlier.  You will be get fatal exceptions at start up.

If the instructions say that you need to checkout and build from source ... then that is what you need to do.

---

> ... but i dont want to use git

If you really, really don't want to use git, you could *hire a consultant* to do the work for you.  :-)

---

> so how can i change the java version

If you are asking if there is some way to tweak a WAR file, then AFAIK there isn't one.  In fact, it is not the WAR file *per se* that is the issue.  Rather, it is the "magic number" in each of the ".class" files that gives the classfile minor version number.  Even if you could rewrite the minor version number, there is no guarantee that the tweaked classes would work as expected on a Java 7 JVM.

Comment: hey, thank u for answer. the reason not usind heroku built in git is,that jenkins is unable to fetch from there :D

Comment: Well it would seem that the solution is to solve >>that<< problem ... i.e. work out how to get Jenkins to fetch from Heroku's git.  But my answer still stands.  It is not sensible to modify (hack) the WAR files as you were proposing in your question.